# Service bound / created to / by a component (observer pattern)

Tags: angular, observer-pattern, eventemitter

Is there a way to create a service which is "bound" to a component or better said: a service which can be **created** by a component?

I have the following situation:

Somewhere on my page is a searchbox. All components on the page should be able to subsrcribe to changes from this searchbox and get notified when it changes.

The only way to accomplish this, which came to my mind, was to use a service.
However I don't know how to create the service from my component (I also thought of using a `factory` or a `setValue` etc. when providing the service, however this also doesn't help me (?)).

As you can see in my code I added an workaround where I throw an error if more than one component tries to be "the provider" for the service. However I consider this a ugly hack and would like to do it differently if possible.

My search component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-search-box',
    template: `<input type="text" #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)" />`,
    providers: [SearchService]
})
export class SearchBoxComponent implements OnInit {

    private _updateSearchFunc : (searchValue: string) => void;

    constructor(private _searchService: SearchService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._updateSearchFunc = this._searchService.registerAsProvider();

        // if another component would also try this, it would result in an exception, so it's kind of the "first come first serve" principle..
        //this._updateSearchFunc = this._searchService.registerAsProvider();

        var activeTab = this._cookieManager.get(Constants.CookieNameActiveTab);
        if (activeTab) {
            this._router.navigateByUrl("/" + activeTab);
        }
    }

    onKey(value:string) {
       this._updateSearchFunc(value);
    }
}
```

My service:

```
export class SearchService {
  private _searchValueChangeEventEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  private _hasProvider = false;

  constructor() {}

  registerAsProvider() : (searchValue: string) => void {
      if (this._hasProvider) {
          throw new Error("There's already a provider registered!");
      }

      this._hasProvider = true;
      return this.emit;
  }

  subscribe(callback : (searchValue: string) => void) {
    return this._searchValueChangeEventEmitter.subscribe(callback);
  }

  // correct this context
  private emit = (searchValue: string) : void => {
    this._searchValueChangeEventEmitter.emit(searchValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use `valueChanges` observable that [form controls](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AbstractControl-class.html) have?

Comment: Hmm I don't see how this helps..

Comment: Your example looks too complicated for what you're trying to do (; If you make a search form you can subscribe to input control changes much easier...

Comment: but can all components in the whole app get notified for changes? do you have a code xample?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with this approach and also not a better way to do it.

You have to register the service in `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ..., SearchService])` or in the `providers: [SeachService]` of `AppComponent`) otherwise it isn't available for the whole application.

Comment: "Sad" to hear it... but thanks anyway. Yeah about the registering I know..: )